# Ant using wrong Java version

Tags: java, macos, ant

Ant is using Java 1.5, even though I don't have Java 1.5 installed. I have to use ant 1.6.5. It's not a choice to upgrade.

diagnostics has interesting output:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"

./apache-ant-1.6.5/bin/ant  -v | grep -i java
Detected Java version: 1.5 in: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

It seems that there is a configuration that forces ant to run java in 1.5 compatibility. I cannot find this configuration anywhere.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure it is really doing anything Java 1.5 related, like passing -source 1.5 -target 1.5 to the javac build task, or is it simply *misreporting* the version of java you have installed? I suspect the latter. That version of ant may be old enough that it simply doesn't know about any more recent version of java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The oldest ant version I have on my system is 1.7.0 (my organization also has projects that require using an outdated version of ant to build).

If I run `ant -v` with the following build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="ant-test" default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <echo message="${java.version}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Then ant 1.7.0 reports:

> Detected Java version: 1.6 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre

But later on, it displays:

> [echo] 1.8.0_25

If I run it with ant 1.8.4 or ant 1.9.3, which I also have installed, it reports:

> Detected Java version: 1.8 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre

As expected. So this is simply a case of an old version of ant which is misreporting the version of Java that it has detected because it doesn't know about newer versions. I don't believe it will actually cause any problems for you building with Java 1.6.0_37.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are correct and it does not affect the compiler version. The value of <echo>${ant.java.version}</echo> is 1.5, and we use that in a few place.